# Accessing User objects through User.objects.filter for a profile page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

How can i query **User** model to get user informations like: username, email, first name, and last name into his profile. I want to display all these information in his profile page.

as you can see here in the **Profle** view i'm willing to access user email, but how can i query the database to get all these information in the profile page ?

```
def profile(request, pk):
    user_profile = User.objects.filter(email=request.user)


    context = {'user_profile':user_profile}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

the profile template:

```
  <p>{{user.email}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by doing this in the profile view:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    user_context = get_object_or_404(User,id=pk)     
    context = {'user_context':user_context}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

I can now be able to access all user information in the template by:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <p>Email: {{user.email}}</p>
        <br>
        <p>Username {{ user.username }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: {{user.email}} (and {{user.username}}) in your template is the same as {{request.user.email}} - and it will work without any get_object _or_404 call.   If you are looking up a user that is not the same as the logged in user, eg, a logged in user is looking up another user's profile, then you will need to use the get_object _or_404  and refer to the results via {{ user_context.email }}

Comment: I have try your answer for the first time before others answer but it did not works even though it does not shows any error but when i try to use: **<p>Email : {{single_user.email}}</p>** in my template it did shows nothing that's why i did not accept it as a recommended answer sir.

Comment: @DeeAdamu First thing, you haven't shown from where you are accessing `pk` in your `profile` view, the answer I showed was the minimal reproductible example, and `{{single_user.email}}` maybe shown nothing, since the pk or id of `User` model must not match with that `pk` which are you are accessing in the view, and `{{user.email}}` in your case works because `user` gives you information about current logged in user, if you're not logged in, it will give  error that `user matching query does not exist` and also after django 3.0 it is better to query through `request`.

Comment: @DeeAdamu It is better if you write `{{request.user.emai}}` for getting information about current user rather than using `{{user.email}}` and your answer does not match view, you are passing `user_context` which contains single_user after querying through `get_object_or_404`, but in your template file you are showing future readers directly from `user` , which is not worth it, then why you access single object in the view, you can simply maintain a condition that `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`, then show it all information, my answer shows exact from that way which will help.

Comment: **user matching query does not exist** this is what i want for every user when he/she try to visit **profile** and I added the **@login_required(login_url='login')** which will help to not allowed user to login to profile page without he/she is authenticated. I hope you understand sir

Comment: @DeeAdamu That's also a way, then why you accessed a single_user through `get_object_or_404(User,id=pk)` if you are not using it in the template for showing email and username?

Comment: @SunderamDubey what if want another user to be able to see the page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the logged_in user details, you already have that as part of the request object.  So you can use the following in your template without doing a lookup in your view:

```
<p>Username: {{request.user.username}}</p>
<p>Email: {{request.user.email}}</p>
```

If you want to use the PK value being passed to your view, so that a visitor can visit the profile of another user (eg, the Primary Key is to identify another user account) you can do a lookup on that.  As Sunderam Dubey notes, the best method for that is via a get_object_or_404() call in your view

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,id=pk)     
    context = {'user_context':user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
<p>Email : {{user_context.email}}</p>
<p>Username : {{user_context.username}}</p>
```

Note the variable object names with _context at the end. You don't have to follow this naming convention, but what's important is that the things I have named 'user_context' have the same name.

Comment: Well spotted - I focussed on the one problem at the expense of the other.  I have updated my answer (with attribution) and included another option.

Comment: This won't works until I change the name of the user variable to **user_context** and pass it to my **context dictionary** like **context = {'user_context':user_context}** and in my template instead of **user_context. email** I did **user.email** and it work. Please edit your answer like mine and I will mark it as recommended answer for future use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access only current logged in user information so you should not use `filter()` as it gives you queryset and used via loops which we run in templates. You should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)<sup>[django-doc]</sup> for displaying data of single object. It gives 404 if found nothing.

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile(request, pk):
    single_user = get_object_or_404(User,pk=pk)


    context = {'single_user':single_user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Template file

```py
{% if single_user %}
    <p>Email : {{single_user.email}}</p>

    <p>Username: {{single_user.username}}</p>
    <p>first name : {{single_user.first_name}}</p>
    <p>last name: {{single_user.last_name}}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>user is not coming</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello @Sunderam Dubey passing `request.user.id` is same as accessing user directly in template eg.(`request.user`) instead of passing `request.user.id` paas *pk*

Comment: @AnkitTiwari see previous edit, does that was right? What about `(User,pk=request.user.pk)`?

Comment: It's depending on situation if user want to access only his/her profile info then it's good to use Django auth context processor eg(`request.user`) but what if user want's to see another user's profile then filtering with `request.user.id` will result current user's profile.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari In previous revision, I wrote `(User,pk=pk)`, is that right? Actually, I haven't debug the code.

Comment: Yes, it was right

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I thought may be OP doesn't understand it, then I changed, and also OP doesn't showed the template so it is not confirm that the `pk` which is coming from route is of user, or of something else.