# User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_image' when creating user

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-users

i created a user registration form using **from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth** but when i try to submit the form instead of creating a new user it's throws me an error like: **TypeError at /register/
User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_image'** ? is anybody who know what's wrong with my code please ?

the register template:

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name">
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name">
                </div>
                
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Enter Your Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Repeat Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2">
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Profile Image</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="profile_image">
                  </div>

                <br>
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: dodgerblue;">Already Have An Account</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Create</button>
            </form>
```

this is my profie_image template.

```
<div class="mb-3">
                <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Profile Image</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="profile_image">
              </div>
```

the register view:

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        profile_image =request.POST['profile_image']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email or user name Already taking')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password, profile_image=profile_image)
                user.save();
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: it should be `user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)` By default the `User` does not have field called `profile_image` if you want to add image there then i advice you to create an other model and inside that modal add `OneToOneField` that is related to the user and add profile_image there.

Comment: what about **profile_image =request.POST['profile_image']** sir ? i want my user to have a profile image sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem as i said in the comment you can just create an other model

1)models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatars/")
    #you can other fields here if you want

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

2)run `python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate`
3)

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        profile_image =request.POST['profile_image']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email or user name Already taking')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
                Profile.objects.create(user=user,profile_image=profile_image)
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

**NB:**DO not forget to import the Profile model.
5) An other option is to extend the User model you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204210/15042684

Comment: thank you sir but How can i access user profile using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360954/18982103

Comment: to get the profile you can just use this : `user_context = get_object_or_404(User,id=pk)` `profile_image = user_context.profile.profile_image.url` now in your context you can have something like this `context = {'user_context':user_context,'profile_image':profile_image}` and in your template you can have this `<img src="{{ profile_image}}"/>` to show the current user profile image

Comment: The profile_image shows only for a **Super user** not others user's that are not super user. sir

Comment: it show image for only super user not others that are not sir

Comment: @DeeAdamu then it means that only superuser has a profile_image

Comment: why ? I mean How can i make sure everyone can own a **Profile_image** in his/her profile page sir

Comment: @DeeAdamu during the registration you can ask them to upload an image and make that field required or you can add a default image for all users so that the user can edit his profile by providing a new picture.

Comment: How can i did this sir ? How can i allow user to edit his profile and how can i make the default image for all user's